# creating a login system using xcode?

Tags: php, iphone, xcode

I'm trying to create an iPhone app using xcode, and I want to know if I can authenticate users remotely using https i.e

- user enters their username and password
- send the variables to a php file
- and gets the results back!

I know how to sort everything out in terms of php, but in the xcode side I'm really stuck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to start [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/GS_Security_iPhone/index.html). Also doing a google search on example https code and security in iphone sdk will surface quite a number of links and tutorials.